# Showing $f=\overline{f}$ a.e. with some finite measure hypothesis.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

So given the sequence $\{ f_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, I found that there exists a subsequence $\{ f_{n_k} \}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ converging weakly to an $\overline{f}\in \textit{L}^p(E)$, so by definition

$$\int_Egf_{n_k} \longrightarrow \int_Eg\overline{f} \mbox{ per } k\rightarrow +\infty \mbox{, } \forall g\in \textit{L}^p(E) \mbox{ (for Riesz's rapresentation, with } \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1\mbox{).}$$

I also know that

$$\int_Ff_n \longrightarrow \int_Ff \mbox { per } k\rightarrow +\infty \mbox{, } \forall F \mbox{ measurable s.t. } |F| <+\infty$$

I would like to conclude that $f=\overline{f}$ a.e. Any suggestions? Also I put my (brief) attempt below.

---

I was about to conclude saying that taking $g=\chi_F$, then
$$\int_Ff_{n_k} \to \int_F\overline{f}=\int_Ff$$
means that $f=\overline{f}$ a.e., but I then realized that I cannot do that becouse I did not suppose they were non-negative.

So could I procede like this?

Taking $g=\chi_{F\cap \{ f-\overline{f}\ge 0 \}}$ and conclude that $f=\overline{f}$ a.e. on $\{ f-\overline{f}\ge 0 \}$, and in the same way $f=\overline{f}$ a.e. on $\{ f-\overline{f}< 0 \}$?

Becouse if I can do that then $f=\overline{f}$ a.e. as I wanted.

Comment: What  is $E$ and what type of measure on $E$ are you considering? This result is fasle in a general measure space but true in sigma finite spaces.

Comment: Let's assume it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, with the lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using  the fact that if $\mu (E\cap F)=0$ for every set $F$ of finite measure then $\mu (E)=0$. This requires a proof. There exist sets $F_n$ of finite measures increasing to $\mathbb R^{n}$ (e.g.: $F_n =\{x; \|x\| \leq n\}$). We get $\mu (E)=\lim \mu (E\cap F_n)=0$.

Comment: It is a bit confusing because I am not looking to prove that the whole space ha null measure. I guess you mean $\mu(E\cap \{f\not=\overline{f} \}) =0$?

Comment: @Measureme You wrote: Taking $g=\chi_{F\cap \{ f-\overline{f}\ge 0 \}}$ and conclude that $f=\overline{f}$ a.e. on $\{ f-\overline{f}\ge 0 \}$. What you get is $F\cap \{ f-\overline{f}\ge 0 \}$ has measure $0$ on $\{f \geq \overline f\}$. To drop this $F$ you have to use the argeument I gave.